# How Can I implement covariance of training samples by Python?

Tags: python, covariance, mahalanobis

I want to implement the covariance of training samples, which can be used when calculating the Mahalanobis distance. How can I implement this equation in Python?

I referenced that image in 'A Simple Unified Framework for Detecting
Out-of-Distribution Samples and Adversarial Attacks'.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: in that image, u(c) is is the mean of multivariate Gaussian distribution of
class c and f(x) denotes the output of the penultimate layer of DNNs. i want to know how can i calculate the inverse of the covariance of training samples but the determinant is 0, so i can't proceed. How can I calculate the inverse of that image covariance ?